# Period of recurrence relation mod p

Tags: combinatorics, recurrence-relations, periodic-functions

For a recurrence relation like $$f(n)=((k-2)*f(n-1)+(k-1)*f(n-2) )\bmod p$$ with initial conditions .This recurrence holds for n>=4
$$\begin{align}f(1)&=k \bmod p\\ f(2)&=k*(k-1) \bmod p\\f(3)&=k*(k-1)*(k-2) \bmod p\end{align}$$
where $p=10^9+7$, how will we find the period. The sequence will surely be periodic with period $\leqslant p^2$.

Comment: What is $k$, some given integer constant?

Comment: Yes, k is constant k>=3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** For $n >1,$ $f(n)= (k-1)^{n}+(k-1) (-1)^n \mod p.$
 Proof by induction.

Then  for $k, (k-1,p)=1$  we have 
$$
f(p-1)=(k-1)^{p-1}+(k-1)=1+(k-1) \mod p=k =f(1).
$$

Comment: for example, by  induction...

Comment: I edited my post and add a proof

Comment: Sry leox, i forgot to add a condition, i have added that now, please read the question again

Comment: Now  that is another problem

Comment: Could you elaborate on your proof by induction

Comment: Just show  that $f(n+1)=(k-1)^{n+1}+(k-1) (-1)^{n+1}.$

Comment: but how did you come to this relation? how did u derive it? and now what of the periodicity.

Comment: i mean how did it came by u that f(n) could be (k−1)^n+(k−1)(−1)^n

Comment: Period is $p-1.$ We have $f(n+(p-1))=f(n).$

Comment: I prove that by induction. Just read somewhere what it  mean "A proff by induction". How I came for the relation does not matter for this kind of proof.